# Checking that a matrix is positive semidefinite with a given rank (in Julia)

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numeric

I am writing a function that checks if a matrix `X` is positive semidefinite with a given rank `k`. To do this, I compute the eigenvalues of `X`, and I check that exactly `k` of them are positive and the rest are 0. Here's what I have so far:

```
using LinearAlgebra    

function ispossemdef(X::AbstractMatrix, k::Int, ϵ::Real = 1e-10)

    n = size(X, 1)                   #  dim of X

    !issymmetric(X) && return false  #  short-circuit if X is asymmetric
    k > n && error("k > n")          #  throw error if k > n

    eigs = eigvals(X)                #  eigenvalues of X in ascending order

    z = eigs[1:(n - k)]              #  the values that should be zero
    p = eigs[(n - k + 1):end]        #  the values that should be positive

    n_minus_k_zero_eigenvalues = norm(z) < ϵ
    k_positive_eigenvalues     = all(p .> ϵ)

    return n_minus_k_zero_eigenvalues & k_positive_eigenvalues

end
```

Is there a better algorithm for doing this? Better might mean faster (avoids computing the eigenvalues), or more numerically stable (lets me get away with a stricter error tolerance).

For example, the `isposdef` function (which is the `k = n` special case of what I'm doing) works by attempting to compute the Cholesky factor of `X`, and reporting back with whether or not it could. Can I generalize this procedure to semidefinite matrices? If so, is it better than checking the eigenvalues?

Comment: If the matrix is `Symmetric` or `Hermitian`, which you already ensure in your code, then can't you use `eigvals` with value boundaries of `0` and `Inf`. If there is a negative eigen value, you can check it with `length` of the result. If the matrix is not PSD at all, then this might run faster since negative eigen values will not be calculated. If you need to copy the matrix into a `Symmetric` or `Hermitian` matrix, you might want to use [`eigvals!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html#LinearAlgebra.eigvals!) instead, since original matrix will not be affected..

Comment: This might as well be a question to Math StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work on all matrices, but have you looked at

```
using LinearAlgebra   # for julia 1+

help> isposdef
```

at the isposdef() function?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to generalize it to semidefinite matrices with a prescribed rank. isposdef works by attempting to compute the Cholesky factor of the matrix and reporting whether or not it was successful. Not sure how that procedure would generalize to semidefinite matrices. If it does and it's better than what I'm doing, that's the sort of thing I want to know. Editing the question to mention this.